# cannot open file C:\Cassandra/logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, garbage-collection, powershell-3.0, cassandra-3.0

I am facing below issue with Cassandra while installing it in Windows. I tried searching in the forum but no luck.

Below are the steps that I performed while I tried to install Cassandra:

1. Placed unzipped Cassandra files under C:\Cassandra folder.
2. Made environment variables entries for Java 1.8 as `JAVA_HOME`, Python 3.6.2 as `Path` and Cassandra 3.11.1 as `CASSANDRA_HOME` in the system variables settings.
3. While I tried to run Cassandra on CMD terminal, it gives me the below error:

   ```
   Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup
   scripts.
   *---------------------------------------------------------------------*
   *---------------------------------------------------------------------*

       WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
       It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
       for performance and stability reasons.

   *---------------------------------------------------------------------*
   *---------------------------------------------------------------------*
   Failed 64-bit check. Re-running to get version from 32-bit
   *---------------------------------------------------------------------*
   *---------------------------------------------------------------------*

       WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
       Performance of this node will suffer.
       Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.

   *---------------------------------------------------------------------*
   *---------------------------------------------------------------------*
   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Cannot open file C:\Cassandra/logs/gc.log
   due to No such file or directory

   Error occurred during initialization of VM
   Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
   ```

Comment: From the looks of it you don't have enough memory. I think the gc.log No such file or directory is a misnomer.

Comment: The last line is probably the relevant error.

Comment: my java version was of 32-bit. I installed 64 bit version and the problem solved. thanks!

Comment: For `gc.log` there is ticket in Cassandra: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14142 - but this is just a warning. Directory will be created on first start, and next starts will not report it